# Use result of post in a subsequent post request

Tags: node.js

I'm a newbie and have little knowledge, I apologise in advance.

I have been trying to find examples on making subsequent post requests using data from the first request.

Scenario, making a request to obtain an auth token which will then be used on subsequent requests in the header.

E.g. request 1 is a POST and returns an access_token object
request 2 is a POST and requires the access_token object from request 1 in the headers.

I have successfully made the request 1 with request-promise but don't know how to pass that to the 2nd requests options.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into "promise chaining". You should make the second request in the `.then((resp) => ...)` callback, where you have access to the response data from the first request. If you `return` the second request promise, you can continue the chain.

Comment: Thank you! I did try (and failed) at promise chaining so thought perhaps that wasn't it. But your comment made me make it work and it does. Appreciated!